# Elasticsearch bulk/batch indexing with python requests module

Tags: indexing, elasticsearch, python-requests

I have a smallish (~50,00) array of json dictionaries that I want to store/index in ES. My preference is to use python, since the data I want to index is coming from a csv file, loaded and converted to json via python. Alternatively, I would like to skip the step of converting to json, and simply use the array of python dictionaries I have. Anyway, a quick search revealed the bulk indexing functionality of ES. I want to do something like this:

```
post_url = 'http://localhost:9202/_bulk'
request.post(post_url, data = acc )    # acc a python array of dictionaries
```

or

```
post_url = 'http://localhost:9202/_bulk'
request.post(post_url, params = acc )    # acc a python array of dictionaries
```

both request give a [HTTP 500 error]

Answer (score 3):

My understanding is that you have to have one "command" per line (index, create, delete...) and then some of them (like index) takes a row of data on the next line like so

```
{'index': ''}\n
{'your': 'data'}\n
{'index': ''}\n
{'other': 'data'}\n
```

NB the new-lines, even on the last row.

Empty index objects like above works if you POST to ../index/type/_bulk or else you need to specify index and type I think, have not tried that.

Answer (score 3):

You the following function will do it:

```
def post_request(self, endpoint, data):
   endpoint = 'localhost:9200/_bulk'
   response = requests.post(endpoint, data=data, headers={'content-type':'application/json', 'charset':'UTF-8'})

   return response
```

As data you need to pass a String such:

```
{ "index" : { "_index" : "test-index", "_type" : "_doc", "_id" : "1681", "routing" : 0 }}
{ "field1" : ... , ..., "fieldN" : ... }
{ "index" : { "_index" : "test-index", "_type" : "_doc", "_id" : "1684", "routing" : 1 }}
{ "field1" : ... , ..., "fieldN" : ... }
```

Make sure you add a "\n" at the end of each line.

Comment: what is the datatype of your data, shouldn't it be list of dicts?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about Python, but did you look at [Pyes](https://github.com/aparo/pyes)?
Bulk is supported in Pyes.